# Flash movie doesn't ask permission for accessing microphone in Google Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome, microphone, recording

I have embedded an online-call on a website.
You can see it here right under the price block: http://www.sapato.ru/catalog/detail/407652/
Everithing works fine in all browsers except Google Chrome. Flash plugin in Chrome doesn't ask permission to use microphone and doesn't call. Any suggestions?
P.S. The size of the Flash object on the page is enough for displaying the dialog.
At first size of Flash block was the issue but it didn't prevent flash element from calling to our call-centre even though caller couldn't been heard. Now we fixed the size and dialog pops up in all major browsers except Chrome. It feels like Flash movie in Chrome doesn't come to using microphone.
Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: For what it's worth, it works as expected, shows the permission dialog, when I test it now with Chrome on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your application window size must be at least 215 x 138 pixels, the minimum size required to display the dialog box, or access is denied automatically.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html)

Comment: No, that's not an issue here. The size is enough for displaying the dialog box.

Comment: i can't see that flash object right now, but i've measured it on a screenshot before posting, its height was about 70px

Comment: I'm really sorry for malfunctioning of the page. Our load-balancers are pretty buggy today. Soon everything will work fine, any help is appreciated.
One additional detail. Block containing flash movie expands when movie loads into it. So it's really not a matter of size I think. There is enough space for dialog box in IE, Firefox, Opera. Revise question for details, I updated it.

Comment: did you try to switch chromes' flash plugin?